# E-olymp: Cake. Giving Wrong Answer

Tags: optimization

[Cake](http://www.e-olymp.com/en/problems/112) This is a e-olymp programming question mathematical optimization.

> In honor of the birth of an heir Tutti royal chef has prepared a huge
>   cake, that was put on the table for Three Fat Man. The first fat man
>   can eat the cake by himself for t1 hours, second - for t2 hours, and
>   the third - for t3 hours.
>
> For what time can the cake be eaten simultaneously by all three fat
>   men?

I had used this formula. But it is giving wrong answer.

```
ans=((t1/3.0)+(t2/3.0)+(t3/3.0))/3.0
```

Please anyone help me.

Comment: Should e-olymp participants figure it out themselves, instead of asking us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

t1 hours/cake
= $\frac{1}{t1}$ cakes/hour.

For all three,
they eat
$\frac1{t1} + \frac1{t2} + \frac1{t3}$
cakes in one hour.

In h hours,
they eat
$h(\frac1{t1} + \frac1{t2} + \frac1{t3})$ cakes.

The time to eat a whole cake
must satisfy
$h(\frac1{t1} + \frac1{t2} + \frac1{t3})=1$
or
$h = \frac1{\frac1{t1} + \frac1{t2} + \frac1{t3}}$.

Answer (score 1):

The "eating speeds" are given in hours per cake. It would be better if they were given in cakes per hour (and man) cause speeds in cakes/hour are additive.

Comment: Sir, Will you please help me by giving equation? Then it will be more clear to me.